# Conditional pips slider jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Hello I got a question regarding using the pips library as an extension of the jQuery UI library.

When you create a slider you do the following thing:

```
$("#someid").slider({});
```

and the slider is created. Now to add thickmarks on the slider I use Jquery UI Slider Pips from Simey.me. To use it you have to set it up like:

```
$("#someid").slider({}).slider("pips", {rest: "false"});
```

Now for some reason I want to make the pip section conditional but I do not know how I could achieve that. I tried the following thing:

```
$("#someid").slider({
    // some options
})
if(boolean_value == true){
    .slider("pips", {                           
            rest: "false",          
    })
}
```

but that obviously does not work. Anyone any ideas how I could solve that? To make my question clear I need to know if it is possible to have the following situation:

```
$("#someid").slider({
    // some options
})
// Conditional section 
.slider("pips", {                           
        rest: "false",          
})
// End conditional section
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following way:

```
//initialize the slider object
var sliderObject = $("#someid").slider({
    // some options
});

if(boolean_value == true){
    //use the previously created slider object to update it
    sliderObject.slider("pips", {                           
            rest: "false"         
    });
}
```